# Leaflet package in R not Plotting all Coordinates from GPX File

Tags: r, leaflet, gpx

I have been working with plotting GPX data from hiking trails.  I can download and extract all of the route data, but when I plot them as polylines, it only plots a small segment.  I have confirmed that the file is complete by running a function that breaks about the GPX file, creates a data frame of lat and lon, and plots them as markers or circlemarkers.  This is very slow for the files that I am working with.

The code is as follows:

```
library(rgdal)
library(maps)
library(htmltools)
library(devtools)
library(leaflet)
library(sp)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(plotKML)
library(maptools)
library(XML)

url <- "http://hiking.waymarkedtrails.org/en/routebrowser/1225378/gpx"
download.file(url, destfile = "pct.gpx", method = "wininet")

pct <- readOGR("pct.gpx", layer = "tracks")

# Import list with shapefiles of the three states the PCT is crossing
mapStates <- map("state", fill = TRUE,
                 plot = FALSE,
                 region = c('california', 'oregon', 'washington:main'))

your.map <- leaflet(pct) %>%

 # Add layer
  addTiles(urlTemplate = "http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png") %>%
  addPolylines(color="red", popup="PCT")  %>%
  addMarkers(-116.4697, 32.60758, popup = "Campo") %>%
  addMarkers(-120.7816, 49.06465, popup = "Manning Park, Canada") %>%
  addPolygons(data=mapStates, fillColor = heat.colors(3, alpha = NULL), stroke = FALSE) %>%

  # Add legend
  addLegend(position = 'topright', colors = "red", labels = "PCT", opacity = 0.4,
            title = 'Legend')
your.map
```

This code works, you get a map, shaded properly and the markers are in the right place.

However, only one small line segment is plotted.  There are 12 lines in the GPX file which I can see by viewing the `pct` object, but it appears to be only plotting one.  No matter which GPX file I download, it's the same problem.

Comment: is it possible you have twelve lines following each other? run plot(pct) and you will see the lines being drawn one after each other forming one big line

Comment: No, because they are of varying lengths and when I unpack them all, I can plot them as circles or markers and they reflect the desired outcome, but it is much slower and data-intensive than the lines.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to a bug in leaflet. There is already an issue filed at github, see [here](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/213).

In **mapview** we have fixed this and MultiLines are drawn correctly. See the issue conversation [here](https://github.com/environmentalinformatics-marburg/mapview/issues/18).

As a reproducible example (taken from the **mapview** issue):

```
library(trajectories)
data(storms)
x = as(storms, "SpatialLinesDataFrame")
plot(x)
library(mapview)
mapview(x)

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addPolylines(data = x)
```

or for your example, simply

```
your.map <- mapview(pct, map.types = "CartoDB.Positron")@map %>% 
  addMarkers(-116.4697, 32.60758, popup = "Campo") %>%
  addMarkers(-120.7816, 49.06465, popup = "Manning Park, Canada") %>%
  addPolygons(data=mapStates, fillColor = heat.colors(3, alpha = NULL), stroke = FALSE) %>%

  # Add legend
  addLegend(position = 'topright', colors = "red", labels = "PCT", opacity = 0.4,
            title = 'Legend')

your.map
```

**NOTE:** This is currently only fixed in the development version of **mapview** which can be installed with `devtools::install_github("environmentalinformatics-marburg/mapview", ref = "develop")`

Comment: Thanks @TimSalbim.  I suspect it is a leaflet bug that might be OS dependent (I am using Windows).  Basically, I was replicating code from this [blog](http://spatialrecology.org/r/leafletmapping/).  It showed successful plots and I was replicating both the code and the data.

Comment: I am not sure this is an OS issue. On Ubuntu 10.04 I have the same issue. I have updated my answer so that this should now look similar to the version of the blog post you mention.

Comment: I am getting an error on the install, looking for a package called `stringi` and so when I run the code above, it goes through all of the data but cannot make a plot.

Comment: And installing `stringi` doesn't help?

Comment: Initially, I was getting a `package 'stringi' does not exist` error, but that is cleared up.  Now I have an rJava issue; associated with i386.  It's a separate issue that I can work through.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: The **rJava** issue should no longer be a problem as the **OpenStreetMap** dependency is now obsolete.